# Count Total from Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, count

I have list table that basically contains same field on each part.

```
- p_ticket1_m_site_data   |  - p_ticket1_ticket  |  - p_ticket1_last_row
- p_ticket2_m_site_data   |  - p_ticket2_ticket  |  - p_ticket2_last_row
- p_ticket3_m_site_data   |  - p_ticket3_ticket  |  - p_ticket3_last_row
```

I can do a count on each table individually:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS tot_sites, IFNULL( COUNT( 
            CASE WHEN p_ticket1_m_site_data.m_date_target = DATE( NOW( ) ) 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE NULL 
            END ),0) AS todays_target, IFNULL( COUNT( 
            CASE WHEN (
            p_ticket1_m_site_data.m_date_target = DATE( NOW( ) ) 
            AND p_ticket1_ticket.t_status =9 ) 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE NULL 
            END ),0
            ) AS todays_achieve, IFNULL( COUNT( 
            CASE WHEN p_ticket1_ticket.t_status =9
            THEN 1 
            ELSE NULL 
            END ),0 ) AS tot_in
            FROM p_ticket1_m_site_data
            LEFT JOIN p_ticket1_last_row ON p_ticket1_last_row.t_m_id = p_ticket1_m_site_data.m_id
            AND p_ticket1_last_row.t_req_type = '04_int_finish_ack'
            LEFT JOIN p_ticket1_ticket ON p_ticket1_ticket.t_id = p_ticket1_last_row.t_id
            WHERE p_ticket1_m_site_data.m_status =1
```

[image]

What should i do if i want to count all total sites from ticket1, ticket2, ticket3 ?

Please help me guys, thanks . . .

Example use UNION ALL:

[image]

I just using UNION ALL in my code above for ticket1 and ticket2, but its not what i want.
My expectation output is count all the ticket tables, so the view is tot_sites (from all ticket), todays_target(from all ticket), todays_achieve(from all ticket), and tot_in(from all ticket)

Comment: Would the same conditions apply - p_ticket1_ticket.t_status =9 ,p_ticket1_last_row.t_req_type = '04_int_finish_ack', p_ticket1_m_site_data.m_status =1 (obviously slightly amended for 2 and 3)?

Comment: yes, it would be the same @P.Salmon

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Mysql 5.5.41 @P.Salmon

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your tables have the same columns, you should use UNION ALL with CTE

```
WITH CTE AS (

SELECT *
FROM p_ticket1_m_site_data
UNION ALL 
SELECT *
FROM p_ticket2_m_site_data
UNION ALL
...

)
SELECT COUNT(*), ...
FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.m_status = 1
```

[CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)
[UNION ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

Comment: If op is on version 8 or above.

Comment: I don't get it man, could you please tell me for the details ? @Arnaud Peralta

Comment: UNION ALL is an operator who stick the data if two tables got the same columns (that is your case). So the CTE (the clause with WITH) is creating a table instance where all your tables are stick. The final SELECT is your original select but made on the CTE (all your tables)

Comment: I gave you links in my post to the documentation

Comment: Im still confuse to rewrite the query with CTE and Union All man. @Arnauld Peralta

Comment: @aldi You cannot use cte's with the version you are on - but the principal is the same you need to vertically join using union your three sets of tables then use aggregate functions to get the output.

Comment: So just include in your from all of my WITH clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can union the three sets of tables in a sub query and then do your counts in the main query , something like this in principal

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS tot_sites, IFNULL( COUNT( 
            CASE WHEN m_date_target = DATE( NOW( ) ) 
             THEN 1 
            ELSE NULL 
            END ),0) AS todays_target, IFNULL( COUNT( 
            CASE WHEN (m_date_target = DATE( NOW( ) ) 
            AND t_status =9 ) 
             THEN 1 
            ELSE NULL 
            END ),0
            ) AS todays_achieve, IFNULL( COUNT( 
            CASE WHEN t_status =9
             THEN 1 
            ELSE NULL 
            END ),0 ) AS tot_in
from
(
select * 
FROM p_ticket1_m_site_data
LEFT JOIN p_ticket1_last_row ON p_ticket1_last_row.t_m_id = p_ticket1_m_site_data.m_id
     AND p_ticket1_last_row.t_req_type = '04_int_finish_ack'
LEFT JOIN p_ticket1_ticket ON p_ticket1_ticket.t_id = p_ticket1_last_row.t_id
WHERE p_ticket1_m_site_data.m_status =1
union all
select * 
frOM p_ticket2_m_site_data
LEFT JOIN p_ticket2_last_row ON p_ticket2_last_row.t_m_id = p_ticket2_m_site_data.m_id
AND p_ticket2_last_row.t_req_type = '04_int_finish_ack'
LEFT JOIN p_ticket2_ticket ON p_ticket2_ticket.t_id = p_ticket2_last_row.t_id
WHERE p_ticket2_m_site_data.m_status =1
union all
select * 
fROM p_ticket3_m_site_data
LEFT JOIN p_ticket3_last_row ON p_ticket3_last_row.t_m_id = p_ticket3_m_site_data.m_id
AND p_ticket3_last_row.t_req_type = '04_int_finish_ack'
LEFT JOIN p_ticket3_ticket ON p_ticket3_ticket.t_id = p_ticket3_last_row.t_id
WHERE p_ticket3_m_site_data.m_status =1
) j;
```

Which could be tidied up. If this doesn't work for you please add sample data and expected output for your 3 tables as text to the question and I will review.

Comment: It doesn't work man @P.Salmon with pop up error "Every derived table must have its own alias".

Comment: You didn't copy the whole thing I suspect. The derived table does have an alias J.BTW I over frommed have edited to fix that.

Comment: i've add my expectation output, and what i've tried so far

Comment: Okay my bad sir, but how about the given error "Duplicate column name 't_id' "?

Comment: I'm hopeless at ping pong - make it easy for both of us by adding sample data for your 3 tables as text to the question. - Doesn't have to be much just enough to prove the answer.